# Using CsvHelper in SSIS Projects

Tags: ssis, csvhelper

I am trying to use CsvHelper in my SSIS project specifically as a source component in my data flow.  Unfortunately, SSIS doesn’t integrate with NuGet, so I would think that the CsvHelper DLL needs to be registered to the GAC.  I haven’t worked directly with the GAC in years.  Is it just the CsvHelper DLL that I need to register?  If so, how do I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux of whether you can put something into the GAC is whether the DLL is strongly signed. Looking at the [project](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/58f48104226e3e4f001941a584d9fbd741c432e5/src/CsvHelper/CsvHelper.csproj), I see an entry for an SNK (strongly named key) so that's checked off the list.

## How to find it

Assuming it's on your system from a command/dos prompt

```
cd /d C:\
dir /s /b csvhelper.dll
```

If you can find the specified DLL, then you need to GAC it

## How to GAC it

Open a visual studio command prompt as a local administrator (or find your GAC installation and open a command prompt as an administrator)

```
gacutil.exe -if Path\to\my\dll\cvshelper.dll
```

Note that you *may* need to specify the path to the gacutil.exe

### Gac find

This will be the same mechanism as finding the dll above. Open a command prompt and search for it. Your results may vary but here's what my box looks like

```
C:\>dir /s /b gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe
```

## Lather, rinse, repeat

You'll need to ensure the DLL has been GAC'ed on any box that will be running your SSIS solution so keep track of any hiccups you have doing this on your local machine as it'll need repeating on the actual servers.

Comment: I ended up creating an empty C# project to install CsvHelper.  I found the DLL, but there is also an XML file along with it in the “lib” folder.  Can the XML file be ignored for my purposes?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes it can be ignored. GACUTIL will put the assembly in the correct place for it to be found. I presume the xml is part of the nuget/npm/chocolatey/whatever kids use these days/ manifest but as always with development things - open it up and see what it contains.

Comment: I ended up making an installer for the DLL instead of using GACUTIL due to deployment policies.  Thanks for all your help!